# Reference in square brackets for springer document class svjour3

Tags: bibliographies, citing, sv-classes

I am using springer `svjour3`. I want the reference numbers to be in square brackets in the reference section.

For example:

> [1] Moritz AR, Zamchek N (1946) Sudden and unexpected death of young
>   soldiers. Arch Pathol 42: 459- 494.
>
> [2] Janssen W, Naeve W (1975) Der plötzliche Tod aus natürlicher
>   Ursache. In: Müller B (Hrsg) Gerichtliche Medizin. Springer, Berlin
>   Heidelberg New York, Bd 1, 2. Aufl. S 248-304

What package do I need to include to make reference numbers include in square brackets?

This is my code:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}


%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)

%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)

\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsame,envcountchap,oribibl]{svjour3}   

% onecolumn (second format)

%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathrsfs} 

\usepackage{amssymb} 

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}

%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system


\begin{document}


\begin{thebibliography}{}


% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions

% for authors for reference list style.


\bibitem{Schouten}

 Schouten K, Frasincar F 2016 Survey on aspect-level sentiment analysis, In:IEEE

Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering 28(3):813–830.

\bibitem{Pang}

Pang B, Lee L, Vaithyanathan S 2002 Thumbs up?: sentiment classification using

machine learning techniques, In: Proceedings of the ACL-02 conference

on Empirical methods in natural language processing, 10:Association

for Computational Linguistics,79–86.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile to replicate your current setup? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If your work is intended for publication, check beforehand if biblatex is supported.

Comment: This is the link:

https://codeshare.io/arxbQZ

Comment: @avinash Please include the code in your question. In case the external link stops working at some point, this ensures that your question will still be useful for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine the bib label to include square brackets in the definition:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}   

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Pang}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{Schouten}

 Schouten K, Frasincar F 2016 Survey on aspect-level sentiment analysis, In:IEEE

Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering 28(3):813–830.

\bibitem{Pang}

Pang B, Lee L, Vaithyanathan S 2002 Thumbs up?: sentiment classification using

machine learning techniques, In: Proceedings of the ACL-02 conference

on Empirical methods in natural language processing, 10:Association

for Computational Linguistics,79–86.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]